# Questions tagged [xxx] vs. number of answers

Tags: support, tags

When I click on [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran), I see on the right 130 questions tagged fortran. Which seems a little, since almost every day I see at least one or two questions with that tag, and I've been here a few years now, so ...

When I go to the top users for that tag, I see a number of answered questions (by let's say MSB, who is currently on the top of that list), 317 with a total score of 761, as of this writing.

Why do those numbers differ? Shouldn't I get the whole list of fortran tagged questions, when I go to that tag?

Or am I doing something completely wrong.

Comment: For me it says "1,192 questions tagged"...

Comment: Cue the [meta-tag:status-norepro] ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are most likely limiting your view to the Unanswered tab. This reduces the amount of hits to those questions with the tag that are unanswered. The amount of unanswered questions (at this time) is exactly 130, as illustrated below:

[image]

If you select the "newest" tab for example, you will see all the questions with that tag in a newest-to-oldest ordering.

Comment: Ah, yes. I overlooked that. How can I see the complete list of all questions with that tag?

Comment: You want the "newest", "votes" or "active" tabs.

Comment: What's the difference between them? Aren't "unanswered" "active" any more?

Comment: "Active" is simply an ordering of all questions based on when the last activity was for that particular question. "Unanswered" selects a subset of questions: those without an answer.

Comment: Correction: without an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Chichiray Ah grrrrr yes, you are absolutely right.